# Disable copying a file in FUSE

Tags: python, fuse

I have written a simple pass-through filesystem using `python-fuse`. Now I want to restrict user from copying the file which he is accessing via FUSE. In what way can I implement this?
e.g. Error message should be displayed if he tries to do `cp [source file in FUSE] [destination]` but it should work fine if he does `cat [filename]`

Comment: what about `cat [source file in FUSE] > [destination]`?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to distinguish a copy operation from a open for read, open for write, and a series of read and write operations?

Comment: Got it - it is not possible